# Is there a simple way to import a MySQL file into a SQLite database through javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, mysql, sqlite, cordova

I am working on an Android Phonegap application and building an offline database in the app which will sync with a MySQL database file.
I need to synchronize all data on onDeviceReady() function.

Answer (score 0):

Method to Sync MySQL to SQLite DB

```
$http.post(php + 'actions.php', {"action": "get-name"}).success(function (result) {
 $scope.nameData = result
 busyIndicator("hide")
 }).error(function(result, status){
 alert(status + "\nCouldn't connect to server due to network problem")
 });
```

Creates Unsynced rows data as JSON

```
<?php
include_once 'db_functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $users = $db->getUnSyncRowCount();
    $a = array();
    $b = array();
    if ($users != false){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {       
            $b["userId"] = $row["Id"];
            $b["userName"] = $row["Name"];
            array_push($a,$b);
        }
        echo json_encode($a);
    }
?>
```